# array_slice (or other array_* functions) on ArrayObject

Tags: php, arrays, implementation, arrayobject, slice

I have a question regarding ArrayObject. I wanted to use array_slice in an ArrayObject class and I couldn't. Is there a way to do it, without needing to write an "slice" method to the class that implements ArrayObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a class that wraps php array functions is not that bad idea. Will make code much cleaner.

```
echo $myAry->slice(10, 5)->reverse()->join(", ");
```

Just like a normal language, you know.

Comment: that looks really cool @hakre. @stereofrog, how the data should be accessed inside the slice() method without duplicating data?

Answer (score 6):

You can always work on the array copy:

```
$array = $object->getArrayCopy();
// modify $array as needed, e.g. array_slice(....) 
$object = new ArrayObject($array);
```

There sometime in the past was the idea to make all functions that accept arrays (or probably many of them) to accept ArrayObject as well. But I dunno how far that has gone and if it's still followed. I think ArrayObject is more a behavioural thing than actually replacing the native array in PHP.

Related question: **[PHP Array and ArrayObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1400404/367456)**

Comment: This is easy to implement, but it's bad on memory. If that's important, it will be worth it to just implement your own ArrayObject-like class where you have access to the private array data such that you can manipulate it directly.

Comment: I must admit I have no clue about ArrayObject internals.

Comment: I was looking to avoid the use of getArrayCopy() because of the size of the array (+400k items).

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason that blocks you from using just a standard array firsthand? And/or is extending ArrayObject an option for in your case?

Comment: it's a result from a database, the original class is an ArrayObject with some extra implementations (mostly iterators). extending this class is some messy business

Comment: If you don't want to deal with the array copy or extending the object itself, you could do this vith a decorator or visitor.

Comment: JEEBUS FRACTURED CHROMOSOME. I've been programming in PHP for 15 years and I am STILL learning about further and further inconsistencies in the standard library APIs.

Comment: Yes, we can have these moments. Maybe understand the subtle difference between SPL and the core library ^^